# How to convert SVG into ArrayBuffer to send to a webusb device

Tags: angular, svg, webusb

I have a WEBUSB printer connected to chrome which can print data send from my angular application.
I am able to create a BARCODE in a form of SVG using ngx-barcode. But in which format I should  send it the usb printer. I tried in below way. But it prints some special character text.

```
  const barcodeSvg = this.barcodeElm.bcElement.nativeElement.querySelector('svg');

  const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
  const svgXmlString = serializer.serializeToString(barcodeSvg);
  const typedArraySvg = Uint8Array.from(Array.prototype.map.call(svgXmlString, c => c.charCodeAt(0)));
  this._service.printBarcode(typedArraySvg);
```

And my printBarcode function is

```
  this.device.transferOut(1, printdata)
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Failed to print', error);
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try this one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/encode. Might work

Comment: Another way I could suggest is create a Blob/File (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#example) and then use FileReader to convert it into a BufferArray in easy way

Comment: @Sergey Thanks for the comment. I have a canvas/SVG to send through transferOut(). Does it need to be encoded? How to do that?

Comment: Create a File/Blob from your SVG using it as a source string. Read the file with FileReader to a BufferArray and feed with it your print method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. Here we create a Blob from SVG string and then transform it to the ArrayBuffer with help of FileReader.

```js
    const barcodeSvg = this.barcodeElm.bcElement.nativeElement.querySelector('svg');

    const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    const svgXmlString = serializer.serializeToString(barcodeSvg);

    // Create a blob from SVG string
    const blob = new Blob([svgXmlString], {
      type: 'image/svg+xml'
    });

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function() {
      var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
      // Feed the service with result ArrayBuffer
      this._service.printBarcode(arrayBuffer);
    };

    // Use reader to transform the Blob to the ArrayBuffer
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Another thing to try is to use it as plain HTML string

```js
    const barcodeSvg = this.barcodeElm.bcElement.nativeElement.querySelector('svg');

    // Create a blob from SVG string
    const blob = new Blob([barcodeSvg], {
      type: 'image/svg+xml'
    });

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function() {
      var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
      // Feed the service with result ArrayBuffer
      this._service.printBarcode(arrayBuffer);
    };

    // Use reader to transform the Blob to the ArrayBuffer
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Also it might worth trying change `type: 'image/svg+xml'` to `type: 'text/html'`